# How to map key to multiple values to dataframe column w/ multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I ultimately want to group by items that have multiple shipping requirements vs ones that have just 1.

I have a pandas df column that looks like this:

```
ID #(column name = ID)
1111
1111,2222
1111,2222
2222,4444,3333
2222,4444
```

How can I create a dictionary object or mapping layer(open to all suggestions) where I can pass any value if it matches criteria and changes to the key value?

For example if the value is `1111, 4444` then change it to `Express Shipping, Standard Shipping` and have that be in the same dataframe.

I ultimately want to group by items that have multiple shipping requirements vs ones that have just 1.

```
1. shipping_num = (1111, 2222, 3333, 4444).

2. shipping_map = (Express shipping, Standard Shipping, 2-day shipping, 1-day shipping)



*NEW_SHIPPING MAP COLUMN*
Express shipping
Express shipping, Standard Shipping
Standard Shipping, 1-day shipping,2-day shipping
Standard Shipping, 1-day shipping
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mapping dictionary from `shipping_num` and `shipping_map`, then use `str.split` + `explode` to get individual ID numbers from the `ID` column. Then use `map` to get shipping maps; finally use `groupby` + `agg` to get back to original shape:

```
shipping_num = (1111, 2222, 3333, 4444)
shipping_map = ('Express shipping','Standard Shipping', '2-day shipping', '1-day shipping')

mapping = dict(zip(shipping_num, shipping_map))
df['shipping_map'] = df['ID'].str.split(',').explode().astype(int).map(mapping).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
               ID                                       shipping_map
0            1111                                   Express shipping
1       1111,2222                Express shipping, Standard Shipping
2       1111,2222                Express shipping, Standard Shipping
3  2222,4444,3333  Standard Shipping, 1-day shipping, 2-day shipping
4       2222,4444                  Standard Shipping, 1-day shipping
```

Comment: thanks this worked!  Some of the IDS also contain letters so I had to add .astype(str) to the line after I mapped everything.

Comment: @aero8991 if IDs contain letters, then `astype(int)` is probably not needed then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want the code to do. One thing that might help is to set up a dictionary like `MyDict = {1111:"Express Shipping",4444:"Standard Shipping}`. From there, you can do a `df["NewColumn"] = df["ID"].apply(lambda x: MyDict[x])` to translate the numbers into labels.

But it sort of seems like you are interested in using multiple keys?

Another thing that might help is to temporarily convert your "ID" columns to strings (e.g. `df['StrID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)`) and then "split" the column on a comma. (e.g. `df['StrID'].str.split(',')` which would set you up to counting the number of IDs in each column. You can then run a group-by over that.